# How to make deep copy?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

```
VehicleRegistry::VehicleRegistry(){
    vehicles = new Vehicle[4];
    numvehicles = 0;
    maxsize = 0;
}

VehicleRegistry::VehicleRegistry(const VehicleRegistry& vr){

}
```

How to make deep copy of that dynamic array?

Comment: ... by using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
VehicleRegistry::VehicleRegistry(const VehicleRegistry& vr){
    vehicles = new Vehicle[4];
    copy (vr.vehicles, vr.vehicles+4, vechicles); 
    numvehicles = vr.numvehicles ;
    maxsize = vr.maxsize ;
}
```

Don't forget that if you have a deep copy,  you'll need as well a deep assignment operator.

To understand the details, have a look at a tutorial, for example [this one](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/).

This being said, a `vector<Vehicles>` could be much simpler to manage.